# Do you have to do a full crawl if you change Title property mappings

Tags: search, search-results, crawling, crawled-property, index

The Managed Property Title in SharePoint is complex, because the title can mapped to Title in SharePoint, Title property in the document, or extracted from the document Text itself.

We are having an issue where the title that is returned in the search result is the  Text Title on the first slide of the PowerPoint deck.  We enter a title into the SharePoint Title Column and this is being ignored by the search engine.

We have moved the crawled property Office:2, which is the Title Property in the pptx to rank highest, followed by TermTitle crawled property which is the SharePoint Title.

[image]

This has had no effect.  Do I have to do a full crawl for this change to take?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to do a full crawl for this change to take?

Yes. A full crawl will be needed. An incremental will not find any changes as anything that does not change a document or its properties will not cause that item to be reindexed.

You can test your changes by recrawling a single library (Library Settings, Advanced Settings) or a site (Site Settings, Search and Offline Availability).

Comment: I have gone into advanced settings on the library and clicked. Reindex Document Library, but nothing changed.

Comment: It will take a while. It has been scheduled to be reindexed in the next incremental crawl. (15-20 minutes?)